# Testcafe - Loading icon for the hammerhead shadow UI is visible

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am using Testcafe to record a test while uploading a file.  Whenever I select the file to upload, the Loading-icon-hammerhead-shadow-ui is triggered

[Hammerhead shadow UI icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poion.png)

Comment: This is expected behavior. TestCafe uses the `loading-icon-hammerhead-shadow-ui` style to indicate that file uploading is in progress. Are you facing any issues with it?

Comment: Yes, I am.  Once the icon is triggered the page freezes and I am not able to do any more action on the page.

Comment: This behavior sounds like a bug. I suggest you create a ticket in our support center (https://supportcenter.devexpress.com) and share an example where we we can reproduce the issue.